# Python Websocket Server - Receive from one client and send to another

Tags: python, websocket, server

At the moment i'm trying to implement a Websocket Server which receives data from one client and if enough data is collected send this collected data to another client.
Both clients are connecting to the server and if i comment out the whole "if path == "/analyser":" part, receiving data works fine. But if i want to send this data nothing happens not even data is beeing received.

```
websockets.serve(self.handle_connection, "localhost", 8766, max_size=None, ping_interval=None, ping_timeout=None):

    async def handle_connection(self, websocket, path):
        print(f"Client connected with {path}")
        batch_data = []
        if path == "/monitor":
            while True:
                message = await websocket.recv()
                data = json.loads(message)
                batch_data.append(data.get("values"))

        if path == "/analyser":
            while True:
                if len(batch_data) > 18400000:
                    await websocket.send(batch_data.copy())
```